# Materialize CSS tabs content via AJAX

Tags: jquery, css, tabs, materialize

Is there a way to load content of tabs via AJAX on materialize CSS tabs, similar to jQuery UI? https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery UI tabs, and follow the

```
$( function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
      beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.jqXHR.fail(function() {
          ui.panel.html(
            "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
            "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
        });
```

Make sure to include the tabs id in your Materialize CSS and preceding the script tab before the materialize CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can roll your own AJAX request and target the tabs like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.tab', (function(e){
    var url = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: { },
        success: function(data){
            $('#targetElement').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```